# iPhone - how to find out length of the text draw on CGContext?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am new to iPhone app development. I don't know that how to find out length of the arc text that draw on CGContext, if anyone knows please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get string fro strlen(conststring) function,for example if you want to draw string ,

```
    NSString *string =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",startPoint];
    const char *constantString =[string UTF8String];
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(mycontext, (cgpoint), 0, constantString,strlen(constantString));
```

strlen(your char string) returns length of string.